# HTML to Rails, html link to rails link_to

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

How do I write this code into rails using <%= link_to %>.

```
<a href="#">
  <div class="button-large">

    <p>Web Development</p>

  </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<%= link_to "#" do %>
  <div class="button-large">
    <p>Web Development</p>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Glad that helped, please accept the answer by clicking on the tick mark beside the answer! :)